# When I apply the Boolean modifier to an object in blender, nothing is subtracted. How do I fix this?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model a simple chopping board in Blender, however, I'm using a modified circle to cut out a portion of a cube to create it. I am trying to make the hole in the chopping board by using a boolean modifier. But when doing so, nothing is happening. [image: I've roughly drawn how I want the board to be cut, and I've hid the circle as I would do when the boolean modifier works as I would have wanted it to] [image: This is the image that I want to be "booleaned" into the larder prism]

Comment: You can't use an effectively 2-d object like a circle.  For this purpose, pick a cylinder and scale it on differently on the X and Y axis.  Make sure to apply scale.

Comment: @MartyFouts , It's actually a 3D object, I just didn't bother to change the name when I extruded it. (I've added an image for refrence)

Comment: did you check your normals? did you try exact and fast? if both doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to someone in a discord server and they told me that "booleans are infamously picky.  IF there's anything wrong with your geometry - doubles, inside walls, etc - it'll refuse to work." I checked the wireframe and realized that there was, in fact, an inside wall/face.

I quickly fixed that (by removing the verts and reconnecting the lines using F to fill) and it somehow didn't work. Then I played around a bit and changed the **solver** to **Fast** and the indent was created!

[image: before fix]

[image: after fix]